# Improving The Readability of A Function Definition

Tags: python, function, args

I have a function that takes in a variable (T) and a bunch of other parameters. The way that I have it now, I feel as if the function is poorly written and I am wondering if there's a way I can make this read better. Fundamentally, I think that my use of *args is not as clear as it could be, but I am not sure how you would pass through a list of parameters and perform the calculations without making the explicit variable assignments through the indexing process. The code works right now, but I think there's a lesson to be learned with using *args for other readers.

```py
ovi_params = [4.6, 0.10, 27.8, 3.1, 0.368, 0.0052]
egg_params = [7.0, 0.02, 30.1, 4.4, 0.256, 0.0237]
L1_params  = [3.6, 0.1, 29.3, 3.8, 0.240, 0.01082]

def rate_curve(T,*params):
    Tb = params[0][0]
    deltab = params[0][1]
    Tm = params[0][2]
    deltam = params[0][3]
    omega = params[0][4]
    psi = params[0][5]


    # Component 1 
    c1 = math.exp( omega*(T-Tb) )
    # Component 2
    c2 = (Tm - T)/(Tm - Tb)
    # Component 3
    c3 = math.exp( -omega*( (T-Tb)/deltab) )
    # Component 4
    c4 = (T-Tb)/(Tm-Tb)
    # Component 5
    c5 = math.exp( omega*(Tm-Tb) - ((Tm-T)/deltam) )
    # Component 6
    c6 = psi*(c1 - c2*c3 - c4*c5)

    return c6
```

Comment: Why can you not simply give the parameters to the function, and do the variable  asignments before the function call? I think your function looks quite clear, maybe add a docstring for readability, though that would work better with separate parameters rather than with your current `*params`.

Comment: If you want to keep those values bundled together, I would highly recommend using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are using `*params` instead of just `params`?  You only access the first set of params in the list, so you might as well just pass that one by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better suited to the CodeReview Stack Exchange but here are my thoughts: 
 the problem (if you want to call it that) with the current function is that it is behaving *too* flexibly, at the expense of clarity.

Firstly, the parameter variables (`ovi`, `egg` and `L1`) are lists, which suggests to the reader that they may need to vary in size or might be modified by `rate_curve` in some way (e.g. a call to `pop()` or `append()`).  However, that is not the case as we know them in their entirety from the get go.  Also, you have to read `rate_curve` in order to understand which values are in which order in the list.  As commentators have pointed out, `NamedTuple` gets around these issues.

Secondly, the function is using the special `*args` function parameter.  As I'm sure you know, this allows a function to take a variable number of arguments.  In other words, you could call `rate_curve(t_value)` or `rate_curve(t_value, param1, ..., param20)` or `rate_curve(t_value, params)`.  Again, this doesn't give the user of the function any hint as to what should be passed in when it knows exactly what it wants passed in.

Here are two options, which both use `NamedTuple`.  I prefer the second and I suspect that maybe the original function author was aiming for it and then got a bit confused.

```or-tag-here
import math
from collections import namedtuple

Parameters = namedtuple("Parameters", "Tb deltab Tm deltam omega psi")
ovi_params = Parameters(4.6, 0.10, 27.8, 3.1, 0.368, 0.0052)
egg_params = Parameters(7.0, 0.02, 30.1, 4.4, 0.256, 0.0237)
L1_params = Parameters(3.6, 0.1, 29.3, 3.8, 0.240, 0.01082)
# if you manually indent whitespace, you have too much time on your hands


def rate_curve(T, params):
    Tb = params.Tb  # use the member variable names
    deltab = params.deltab
    Tm = params[2]  # or stick to using the indices
    deltam = params[3]
    omega = params[4]
    psi = params[5]

    # Component 1
    c1 = math.exp(omega * (T - Tb))
    # Component 2
    c2 = (Tm - T) / (Tm - Tb)
    # Component 3
    c3 = math.exp(-omega * ((T - Tb) / deltab))
    # Component 4
    c4 = (T - Tb) / (Tm - Tb)
    # Component 5
    c5 = math.exp(omega * (Tm - Tb) - ((Tm - T) / deltam))
    # Component 6
    c6 = psi * (c1 - c2 * c3 - c4 * c5)

    return c6


print(rate_curve(1, ovi_params))  # pass in the named tuple
print(rate_curve(1, egg_params))
print(rate_curve(1, L1_params))


def rate_curve2(T, Tb, deltab, Tm, deltam, omega, psi):
    # Component 1
    c1 = math.exp(omega * (T - Tb))
    # Component 2
    c2 = (Tm - T) / (Tm - Tb)
    # Component 3
    c3 = math.exp(-omega * ((T - Tb) / deltab))
    # Component 4
    c4 = (T - Tb) / (Tm - Tb)
    # Component 5
    c5 = math.exp(omega * (Tm - Tb) - ((Tm - T) / deltam))
    # Component 6
    c6 = psi * (c1 - c2 * c3 - c4 * c5)

    return c6


print(rate_curve2(1, *ovi_params))  # expand the named tuple into normal parameters
print(rate_curve2(1, *egg_params))  # it would work with a normal tuple too
print(rate_curve2(1, *L1_params))
```